# HystrixCommand only works with Spring Service or Component?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix

Does Spring Hystrix only work with @Service and @Component?

I had a class that was defined as a @RestController and my HystrixCommand would not fire, the method would execute but not behave as a HystrixCommand. When I made a @Service class and put the HystrixCommand method and fallback into it the HystrixCommand would work properly.

What are the appropriate Spring annotations that can be used with @EnableHystrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you described the appropriate places.  We have an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/21#issuecomment-110173136) that mentions support for controllers.